# codename one native google map show in small rectangle

Tags: codenameone

I am using Mapcontainer to display native maps on android device. the map container is added to a form which has a text field and a button. When I run this on device the map loads in a very small rectangle as shown in the below image link. How can I increase the map size?
Image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9eBv.jpg

Comment: Please provide the code you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by placing the map in a form with FlowLayout. Place the map container at the center of a BorderLayout form.

- change the form layout to BorderLayout
- Move the button and the textfield inside a new container, place this container at the North position of the form.
- Place the map container at the center of the form